# What does "del aprx" at the end of Python code do?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, for-loop, aprx

Often times a Python code for ArcGIS Pro requires the statement "del aprx" at the very end, what does this statement do and is it necessary?

I recently ran a Python snippet changing data sources for a list of feature classes. Absentmindedly, I didn't include "del aprx" at the end, and the snippet ran successfully, but program froze afterward.

Could the freeze be related to my omission of "del aprx"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python `del` means delete the object which would release memory and file locks. So if you saw `del abc,bob,x` this would mean delete the objects abc, bob and x, what ever they are. `aprx` is the commonly used name for an ArcGIS Pro project object but the coder could have called it *anything* like banana, but obviously that's a stupid name for the object it represents.

Without seeing the code and the context the object `aprx` is used no one can comment other than to say the coder was proactively releasing memory by deleting unwanted objects.